# Getting date from datepicker wrt different timezones

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I'm using a standard DatePicker and printing the date on top of it. 
For some reason my Date Picker has it's timezone set to IST, which maybe because of the locale.

Let's get into an example:

> DatePicker -> 12:00 PM Date reads -> 06:30:00 +0000

Which is correct as the date will print **UTC** time and **IST** is **UTC+5:30**

Now when I change the timezone of the DatePicker, let's say to London which is **GMT+1**,

> DatePicker -> 12:00 PM Date reads -> 06:30:00 +0000

Where in the date should actually read 11:00:00

How I am changing the DatePicker's timezone:

```
if let tmz = selectTimeZone {

    datePicker.timeZone = tmz
}
```

Comment: can you share some more code related to adding/showing picker?

Comment: While converting date to string Change the DateFormatter timezone. no need to set timezone of Datepicker

Comment: Try this one if further required it's working https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477989/10150796

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue sometime before but for the another reason. Try this hope it will help.

First -

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
var startDate = dateFormatter.string(from: yourdatepicker.date)
startDate = localToUTC(date: startDate)
```

Second we convert this to local to UTC , here we mention the TimeZone to system time

```
func localToUTC(date:String) -> String {

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}
```

Third if you want to conver UTC to your Local time

```
func UTCToLocal(date:String) -> String {
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
 }
```