# i can select time at date picker when i get value from that in UTC so how to convert UTC time to GMT+05:30 to date?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

```
var timeReminder = Date()
let dateFormReminder = DateFormatter()
dateFormReminder.calendar = Calendar.current
dateFormReminder.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
dateFormReminder.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT +05:30")
timeReminder = dateFormReminder.date(from: txt_time.text!)!
```

Image of date picker

[image]

i am not get local time when i am convert time string to date value.
    OUTPUT:- 2000-01-01 07:12:00 +0000

Comment: Can you please share your input Date **txt_time.text!** and your output date format

Comment: txt_time.text! = 13:00 PM                                     
dateFormReminder.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"

Comment: Can you please share you present date picker image?

Comment: and output of txt_time.text! = 13:00 PM        (output/;-2000-01-01 06:30:00 +0000)

Comment: i can add image of date picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to do like this**

`UIDatePicker` display Local DateTime but it returns UTC DateTime. So you need to convert it to Local for getting actual Local Date and time.

```
func GetLocalStringDateFromUTC(date:Date)-> String{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //Your date format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+5:30") //Current time zone different
    let myString = dateFormatter.string(from: date) //according to date format your date string
    return myString //Convert String to Date
}

// For Get date from string
func GetDateFromString(date_string:String,dateFormat:String)-> Date{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat //Your date format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") //Current time zone
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date_string) //according to date format your date string
    return date! //Convert String to Date
}

// For Get time from Date
func GetTimefromDate(date_string:String,dateFormat:String)-> String{

    let dateFormatter_db = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter_db.dateFormat = dateFormat
    let dateFormatter_eventDate = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter_eventDate.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" //Your time format
    let date = dateFormatter_db.date(from: date_string)
    return dateFormatter_eventDate.string(from: date!)
}
```

**Use like this**

```
let date = datePicker.date  // Pass your DatePicker Date Here

print(GetLocalStringDateFromUTC(date: date)) // Local String Date from UTC
print(GetDateFromString(date_string: GetLocalStringDateFromUTC(date: date), dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) // Local Date() from UTC
print(self.GetTimefromDate(date_string: self.GetLocalStringDateFromUTC(date: datePicker.date), dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) // Local Time from UTC
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: i want to return value in date with GMT time not in string type

Comment: @RiteshPatel So simply you can convert **GetLocalDateFromUTC** string date to **Date()** or in that format, you can also return actual date replace by a string

Comment: My output after changes string to date                                                          2018-09-24 17:13:29
Optional(2018-09-24 11:43:29 +0000)
05:13
1999-12-31 23:43:00 +0000

Comment: @RiteshPatel You missed assigning timezone to **DateFormatter()** that's why it's happening. Check my answer. I update for getting all.